# Working on friending system, need to have a way to add friend's id to WHERE query? Same column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok this may be obvious but I am making a friending system but I need to have multiple possible userids for the userid column in my table `activity` but when i use the code below:

```
$q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE userid=:uid");
        $q->execute(array(
            ":uid"=>$user['id'],
        ));
        if($q->rowCount()>0){
            $remainder ="";
            foreach($q as $p){
                $remainder .= "OR `userid` =`".$p['friendid']."`";
            }
        }
        $query = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE `userid`=:id .$remainder. ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");
        $query->execute(array(
            ":id"=>$user['id']
        ));
```

it in fact returns nothing when I `var_dump` the result. Whereas it should have the stream content of the user and all his/her friends.

What have I done wrong here? I cannot seem to find the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two separate queries you can use join:

```
select * from `activity` as `t`
join `friends` as `r` on (`t`.user_id = `r`.user_id)
where  `t`.user_id = :id
```

The actual problem in your code is:

```
$remainder .= "OR `userid` =`".$p['friendid']."`";
                            ^                  ^
```

Remove them.

Also it would be easier to use `IN` instead of repeating the same code in sql query:

```
$remainder = 'AND user_id in (';
$user_ids= array();

foreach($q as $p){
     $user_ids[] =$p['friendid'];
}

$remainder .= implode(',', $user_ids).')';
```

Comment: wait, i think you are on the right track but um... how would I actually implement this I mean is user_id my: user['id']?

Comment: @MuqMan In `where` clause of my first query, you should bind `array(':id' => $user['id'])`

Comment: so the array thing will fit with the query that I am currently using not the one you posted right?

Comment: @MuqMan In my last example array will hold all id that query returns and then `implode` function will convert it to a string to use one in query.

Comment: um... I am a bit confused at this point, what do I need to do to your query so it works with my variables...?

Comment: or could I edit the execute(array()) section to include the other ids?

Comment: You don't need to change anything but what's inside `if($q->rowCount()>0){` with the last solution. And also use updated one, please.

Comment: OK, well I tried them all and what seems to suit me best is yours about dropping the single quotes. Thanks, let me mark this as the answer and vote up!

Comment: You helped me a lot! This is one of the features ESSENTIAL to my site, and I will remember this in the future too :)